# MySQL select instr

Tags: mysql, select, substr

I have a column with the PATH & name & extension of a file.
I would like to select only the name & extension.

example :

`/XMLWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/LOCAL/CURRENCIES/TL_RN_TTH.xml`

How do I select "TL_RN_TTH.xml" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) with a negative parameter:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(path_column, '/', -1)
from your_table
```